# Рекурсивный подсчет записей в таблице

Tags: рекурсия, sql, запрос, mysql

Имеется таблица файлов **files** следующего содержания:

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| dir_id      | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| title       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

и есть таблица папок **dirs**:

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| parent_id | int(11)     | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| title     | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Нужно по заданному ID выводить количество файлов в категории считая внутренние папки.

Comment: @s312, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существует способ сделать это одним запросом.

```
SELECT MAX(`cnt`) as `count` FROM (
  SELECT
  @id:=CONCAT_WS(',',@id, `dirs`.`id`),
  @cnt:=@cnt+(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `files` WHERE `dir_id`=`dirs`.`id`
  ) AS `cnt` 
  FROM `dirs` 
  JOIN (
    SELECT 
    @id:=1 /*Change it!*/, 
    @cnt:=(
      SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `files` WHERE `dir_id`=1 /*Change it!*/)
  )t 
  WHERE 
  find_in_set(`parent_id`, @id)
)t2;
```

По сути это своеобразный цикл, в начале мы устанавливаем переменные `@id` и `@cnt`, а потом на каждой «итерации» добавляем в `@id` новый id директории, а в `@cnt` число файлов в ней. Вот [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7f34/10).

**Недостатки**: поведение присваивания и получения значения одной и той же переменной в одном запросе не совсем определено, в поиске поддиректорий не используются индексы. Хотя, наверное, можно сделать то же самое с помощью `join`.